# DML commit via jdbc

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Hi I have executed the DML query via jbdc statement without giving autocommit and insert,update and delete happens . Can anyone help to understand how it works?

For example

[Sample program](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-update-a-record/)

Comment: Show your DML code and `SELECT` statement that you are running.

Comment: String updateTableSQL = "UPDATE DBUSER SET USERNAME = ? WHERE USER_ID = ?"; PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(updateTableSQL); preparedStatement.setString(1, "mkyong_new_value"); preparedStatement.setInt(2, 1001); // execute insert SQL stetement preparedStatement .executeUpdate();

Comment: Please **edit your question** when including new information. It is extremely hard to read code in comments.

Comment: Also, `autocommit` is the default so you need to show your whole program not just the SQL snippets.

Comment: @APC sample program added

Comment: That sample code does not do anything with regards to `autocommit` . So the default JDBC behaviour applies, which is to commit after every statement. As your experience demonstrates.

Comment: @APC thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

In JDBC, autocommit property is enabled by default when the connection is created. You might need to disable the property explicitly if you want the transaction to be completed only after using commit() function.

For more information, refer the following link,

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html#disable_auto_commit